# BizTalk - Generating schema for carriage return delimited flat file

Tags: biztalk, delimiter, biztalk-2010, flat-file

I am trying to generate schema for a flat file the content of which are separated by carriage returns. Please see a sample of the data from the import file below:

```
12042012  
TDF  
XYZ Industries Limited  
X9090-78900
-
3.4
-
NA
-
-
-  
-
-  
All telephone calls routed to a different no.  
tomorrow is critical. To have the  
documents ready for inspection.

12042012  
TDF  
XYZ Industries Limited
X9090-78900
-
.6
-
NA
-
-
-
-
-
Further prep re hearing/how inital costs  
estimate reached/emails to update XYZ,  
collation of docs fro tomorrow. 1735 - 1815
(-1).
```

In the sample above there are two records. Each record is separated by a carrige return. In turn each field in the record is also separated by carriage return. This is all fine but when it comes to the last field in the record, which is the "Description" field, you will see that there are carriage returns within the text (as they are entered by the user in the source system).

Here in lies the challenge for me, I haven't been able to successfully generate a schema using the Flat File Schema wizard available in BizTalk Server 2010 such that the "Description" field comes out as a single record. Because when I put Line Carriage delimiter it always treats the Description lines as separate records. When I go to validate the schema it always fails. Could somebody point me in the right direction as to what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the source system? If so, you can set an escape character on the record. Assuming the use of a backslash for an escape character, the description field would then contain:

> All telephone calls routed to a different no.\
>   tomorrow is critical. To have the\
>   documents ready for inspection.\